# Show data point values in the legend section. SSRS

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

Is it possible to show the values in the legend section in a chart in SSRS.

Similar to the picture

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Robert Bruckner of Microsoft wrote an article showing something similar here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964128(v=sql.90).aspx. Scroll down to the section titled "Adding Chart Data Labels."